# How to execute downladed installer from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know that for security reasons one can't run locally installed, arbitrary executables from a web page.

However, I just noticed that https://remotedesktop.google.com/access can launch its own Windows installer so it's possible (at least on Chrome 74 and Windows 10)

What happens is:

- I click on the installer download button
- `.msi` installer is downloaded locally to default Downloads folder
- the UI pop-ups with a button to "Accept & Install"
- clicking that button shows a browser alert and after accepting it, launches the installer `.msi` file

This might only be limited to files downloaded from the originating website, which is fine. I just want to replicate this UX for my own desktop software installer.

I tried to poke at HTML / JavaScript of that page with Chrome Dev Tools but it's obfuscated beyond my ability to reverse engineer it.

The question is: what JavaScript APIs allow me to:
* monitor progress of a download initiated by the user from my website
* know the location, in the Downloads folder, of the downloaded file
* execute that file to start installation process

Those are the things that I assume that page is able to do in order to achieve its UX.

Comment: it uses an extension.

Answer (score 1):

I've verified that [@dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) is right: I've tried to do it from a clean install of Chrome and it didn't work that way.

It's only possible when Goggle's Remote Desktop extension is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not possible. Not with a web app anyway.

- Monitor progress of a download: not possible, unless you `fetch` the content, in which case the binary content of your installer will buffer up in your application memory, where you won't be able to do anything with it other than possibly turn it into a blob and then initiate a "client-side download" via a library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver
- But even then, you won't accomplish much other than knowing the progress of the download. You won't know where the file will be saved, and you certainly won't have low level file-system access to it: you won't know its final name, location, and you won't be able to execute it.

This is just the security boundary of the browser that shields low-level operations from your browser app.

As for how Google achieves that user experience, a couple of thoughts:

1. Chrome may examine the digital signature of the incoming file and upon verification that it's from a trusted source (likely only Google), execute it upon download. If this is how they've done it, it's done at Chrome level not at the front-end (any HTML/Javascript) level.
2. Alternatively/additionally, when Google downloads a software onto your PC for the first time, it installs a "Google Download Manager", which is a simple protocol handler that facilitates downloading (and updating) the next pieces of Google desktop software. In presence of this download manager, Google will be able to quickly invoke that private protocol and launch new installers in a smoother, customized experience.

In order to intercept incoming files and do anything with them (locate them, execute them, etc.) you need your application to run at a much lower level than in the browser. Browsers enforce all sorts of security and execution sandboxes to ensure that no front-end app can read, execute, or manipulate files on the host OS.

If, however, you develop an ElectronJS app, which runs in NodeJS runtime, then you'll have all sorts of access to the OS file system, and you certainly will be able to poke and prod around the host OS, write files, execute them, etc. This is in fact how Electron apps (such as Visual Studio Code, etc.) automatically update themselves.